# How to split by symbol and letter

Tags: regex, dart, split

How can I split something like `I have a cat, a dog and a bird` to get `["I have a cat", "a dog", "a bird"]`. I know taht it should be simple, but I don't know how to do it and I have tried some code but I only get to separate by `,`

For example, I have tried:
`var split = text.split(",|and")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use delimiters `/` for the pattern and you might add a space after the comma and before and after `and` to get your expected output.

See the matches in this [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/r1tnIv/1/)

```js
let pattern = /, | and /;
let text = "I have a cat, a dog and a bird";

console.log(text.split(pattern))
```